# Cannot plot or use .tolist() on pd dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

so I am reading in data from a csv and saving it to a dataframe so I can use the columns. Here is my code:

```
filename = open(r"C:\Users\avalcarcel\Downloads\Data INSTR 9 8_16_2022 11_02_42.csv")
columns = ["date","time","ch104","alarm104","ch114","alarm114","ch115","alarm115","ch116","alarm116","ch117","alarm117","ch118","alarm118"]
df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep='[, ]',encoding='UTF-16 LE',names=columns,header=15,on_bad_lines='skip',engine='python')

length_ = len(df.date)
scan = list(range(1,length_+1))

plt.plot(scan,df.ch104)
plt.show()
```

When I try to plot scan vs. df.ch104, I get the following exception thrown:

> 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a None

So what I thought to do was make each column in my df a list:

```
ch104 = df.ch104.tolist()
```

But it is turning my data from this to this:
[before .tolist()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq0K5.png)

To this:
[after .tolist()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32lkF.png)

This also happens when I use `df.ch104.values.tolist()`

Can anyone help me? I haven't used python/pandas in a while and I am just trying to get the data read in first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, the `df.ch104.values.tolist()` code beasicly turns your column into a 2d 1XN array. But what you want is a 1D array of size N.

So transpose it before you call `.tolist()`. Lastly call `[0]` to convert **Nx1 array** to **N array**

```
df.ch104.values.tolist()[0]
```

---

Might I also suggest you include **dropna()** to avoid `'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a Non`

```
df.dropna(subset=['ch104']).ch104.values.tolist()[0]
```

Comment: Hi Enoch, thank you for your answer! How do I transpose a single column of a dataframe? I tried df.ch104.T and df.ch104.transpose() and it didn't seem to help. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I just saw the output pictures you posted. Seems very strange, I am suspecting it has something to do with the UTF-16 LE format.  Could you saving it in a more reliable format and reading it again? df.to_excel('temp.xlsx',index=False)
pd.read_excel('temp.xlsx') and try your code again

Comment: Hi Enoch, so I was looking at the other comment posted by someone else and tried changing the None value that appeared in the last row using .dropna() like you said. I think that fixed the problem actually! I didn't even have to use .tolist(). Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says there are `None` or `NaN` values in your dataframe. You need to check for `None` and deal with them - replace with a suitable value or delete them.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I did this with .dropna() and it seems to have worked. Sorry, the error made it sound like the data type wasn't correct so I wasn't sure since I haven't used this plotting method before.

Comment: you are welcome. If this comment helped you, appreciate if you could hit the answer up.